# Why doesn't contentView containing a label have any height in its scrollView in autolayout?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm creating a scrollView and adding a contentView to it using autolayout. The contentView's height I thought would be determined by the height and constraints of its contents. Since it has a label, shouldn't the contentView's height equal the label height? Only way height exists (in blue in the snapshot) is if adding a height constraint to the contentView. I thought this would be unnecessary since autolayout should know the heights of labels from their intrinsic content size?

[image: scrollview].

```
// Scrollview

_scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
_scrollView.bounces = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{ @"_scrollView" : _scrollView }];
NSArray *verticalConstraints   = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{ @"_scrollView" : _scrollView }];
[self.view addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];


// Content view

_contentView = [UIView new];
_contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[_scrollView addSubview:_contentView];

NSArray *horizontalContentConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{ @"_contentView" : _contentView }];
NSArray *verticalContentConstraints   = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{ @"_contentView" : _contentView }];
[_scrollView addConstraints:horizontalContentConstraints];
[_scrollView addConstraints:verticalContentConstraints];

// Why does height of content view need to be added to get the blue area to show?
NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:5];
[_contentView addConstraint:contentViewHeight];

NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewOuterLeading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewOuterTrailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0];

[self.view addConstraints:@[ contentViewOuterLeading, contentViewOuterTrailing ]];


  // Day label

_dayLabel = [UILabel new];
_dayLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_dayLabel.text = @"Monday";
_dayLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[_contentView addSubview:_dayLabel];

NSLayoutConstraint *dayLabelTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_dayLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *dayLabelCenterX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_dayLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];

[_contentView addConstraints: @[ dayLabelTop, dayLabelCenterX ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because a `UIScrollView` has a content size of (0,0).

You can say it's bounds should be flush with the superview, but that's not actually changing its contentSize. Additionally, you add the contentView, but again you're saying it should be flush with its superview (the scrollview) though since the scroll view's size is still (0,0), you're implicitly saying that the content's view size will be 0,0. It's only after you add a constraint that specifically says 5px do you actually see a bit of the view.

A scroll view will get it's appropriate size from it's contents, so if you instantiated the content view as:

```
UIView * contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainscreen].bounds];
```

The scroll view's content size would be equal to [UIScreen mainscreen].bounds and you would still be satisfying the layout constraints you write.

As you add UI elements to uiscrollview, and arrange them via layout constraints, the scrollview will automatically expand as needed.

I wrote a blog post exactly on this subject, [Programmatic ScrollViews w/ NSLayout](https://flatitronrabbit.wordpress.com/2014/11/20/its-all-in-your-head-programmatic-ui-dev/) ... you may have too look at an older commit to it, but I ran into this exact same issue.

Comment: Interesting. For that I'd need to know the sizes of all components, add them up and calculate a size. I was trying a pure autolayout approach like http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/. It relies on intrinsic content size to get height of the contentView, which get passed to the scrollView through other constraints.

Comment: yea, you may need to know ahead of time of their sizes, or you can calculate at runtime. in theory if you're loading images creating the VFL as `H:|[image1][image2][image3]|` it could take care of itself. nice link too! I have something like that written out as well (but programmatically) but it was such a pain to get it all perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. Adding a constraint from contentView to the bottom of its label made it work. No height constraint is needed for the contentView. Here's the updated code:

```
// Scrollview

_scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
_scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{ @"_scrollView" : _scrollView }];
NSArray *verticalConstraints   = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{ @"_scrollView" : _scrollView }];
[self.view addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];


// Content view

_contentView = [UIView new];
_contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[_scrollView addSubview:_contentView];

NSArray *horizontalContentConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{ @"_contentView" : _contentView }];
NSArray *verticalContentConstraints   = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{ @"_contentView" : _contentView }];
[_scrollView addConstraints:horizontalContentConstraints];
[_scrollView addConstraints:verticalContentConstraints];

NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewOuterLeading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewOuterTrailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraints:@[ contentViewOuterLeading, contentViewOuterTrailing ]];


// Day label

_dayLabel = [UILabel new];
_dayLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_dayLabel.text = @"Monday";
_dayLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[_contentView addSubview:_dayLabel];

NSLayoutConstraint *dayLabelTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_dayLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *dayLabelCenterX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_dayLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *dayLabelBottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_dayLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0];
[_contentView addConstraints: @[ dayLabelTop, dayLabelCenterX, dayLabelBottom ]];
```